# HTML radio buttons allowing multiple selections

Tags: html, forms

In my HTML form I have the below as a set of radio buttons, depending on what radio button you select depends on what the next form `<fieldset>` is revealed, this all works. The problem is for some reason they are working like a check box and not as a radio button. So you can select all options and not just the one at a time.

Can anyone see where this is going wrong in the code below?

```
  <fieldset>
        <legend>Please select one of the following</legend>
        <input type="radio" name="track" id="track" value="track" /><label for="track">Track Submission</label><br />
        <input type="radio" name="event" id="event" value="event"  /><label for="event">Events and Artist booking</label><br />
        <input type="radio" name="message" id="message" value="message" /><label for="message">Message us</label><br />
  </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 173, accepted):

They all need to have the **same** `name` attribute.

The radio buttons are grouped by the `name` attribute. Here's an example:

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Please select one of the following</legend>
  <input type="radio" name="action" id="track" value="track" /><label for="track">Track Submission</label><br />
  <input type="radio" name="action" id="event" value="event"  /><label for="event">Events and Artist booking</label><br />
  <input type="radio" name="action" id="message" value="message" /><label for="message">Message us</label><br />
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 6):

I've done it this way in the past, [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5yuej5q4/):

CSS:

```
.radio-option {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 23px;
    width: 23px;
    background: url(../images/checkbox2.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;
}

.radio-option.click {
    background: url(../images/checkbox1.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<li><div class="radio-option"></div></li>
<li><div class="radio-option"></div></li>
<li><div class="radio-option"></div></li>
<li><div class="radio-option"></div></li>
<li><div class="radio-option"></div></li>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.radio-option').click(function () {
            $(this).not(this).removeClass('click');
            $(this).toggleClass("click");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I quite like that approach, means you get more options for customizing how the check box would look, would you then have a hidden input field to record the result within a form or would you gather that info purely through JS?

Comment: Thanks, and I suppose you could do it either way, @ThePagan.  I did notice that I have two different images...not sure why I hadn't corrected that yet.  Should be one sprite with a background-position change, otherwise there could be image-loading artifacts on mobile.

Answer (score 4):

Try this way of formation, it is rather fancy ...

Have a look at this jsfiddle

[**Button-Radio**](http://jsfiddle.net/6jquM/2/)

```
The idea is to choose a the radio as a button instead of the normal circle image.
```

Answer (score 3):

The name of the inputs must be the same to belong to the same group. Then the others will be automatically deselected when one is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

All radio buttons must have the same name attribute added.

Answer (score 1):

To the radio buttons works correctly, you must to have grouped by his name. (Ex. name="type")

```
 <fieldset>
    <legend>Please select one of the following</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="type" id="track" value="track" /><label for="track">Track Submission</label><br />
    <input type="radio" name="type" id="event" value="event"  /><label for="event">Events and Artist booking</label><br />
    <input type="radio" name="type" id="message" value="message" /><label for="message">Message us</label><br />
```

It will returns the value of the radio button checked (Ex. track | event | message)

Comment: This is the same answer as the accepted one... just with a missing `</fieldset>` tag.