# Entire row of the form clickable

Tags: html

I have this form:

[image]

Which is coded this way:

```
{% for answer in answers %}
    <tr>
       <td>
          <label>
              <input type="radio" name="guess" value="{{ answer.id }}" class="form-radio">
              {{ answer.content }}
          </label>
       </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

But, this way, the user can only clicks on the radio button to answer the question. But, I want to have all the row of the answer clickable. How can I change this code to have the entire row clickable?

Comment: Check this qus: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982993/html-radio-buttons-allowing-multiple-selections and you have define your url pattern in such way that it can accept multiple values....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most browsers will toggle your radio button selection on either

1. Clicking the radio/checkbox widget
2. Clicking the **label** element itself.

You could easily make the entire 'row' clickable by modifying the CSS for your label to be 100% width, and displayed as 'inline-block'

```
label {
    /* whatever other styling you have applied */
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

*As a side note:  It is generally considered bad practice to drop your form data inside a table just for formatting.  I would recommend putting it inside an unordered list, as that's more semantically correct.*

Answer (score 1):

You should alter your html to something like this

```
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="guess" id="guess_{{ answer.id }}" value="{{ answer.id }}" class="form-radio">
      <label for="guess_{{ answer.id}}">{{ answer.content }}</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Sample html [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Y4HdM/)

Comment: Thanks! But this way it's clickable only in the text, not in the entire row.