# Radio Button and Image-Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made an Image-Slider based on Radio Buttons (thanks to some advice of user A.V) as you can see here:

Now, there is one last thing that I would love to do but I have no idea how. I would like to be able to switch to the next image by clicking on the image itself (of course with the selection jumping to the next button, too).

Would be awesome if someone could help. Thanks in advance!

```
JSFiddle
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v4phdL3p/8/

Comment: Always post your code in the question. You saw the warning when you posted a link to jsFiddle without code and chose to try and sidestep the rule by highlight non-code text as code.

Comment: I must admit I didn't get it first :-/ I will take care of it in the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add class "sliderImage" to your image placeholders and then use this code:

```
$(".sliderImage").click(function(){

    var name = $(this).attr("name")
    var selector = "input[checked][name='" + name +"']"
    currrentRadio = $(selector)
    currrentRadio.removeAttr("checked")

    if (currrentRadio.next().attr("name") === name) {

        currrentRadio.next().attr('checked', 'checked').prop("checked",true).trigger("click")

    } else {

        var nextRadio = "input[name='" + name + "']"
        firstRadio = $(nextRadio)[0]
        $(firstRadio).attr('checked', 'checked').prop("checked",true).trigger("click")   

    }

})
```

*EDIT* change changeImage to this (to allow clicking of object to not affect functionality):

Here is the working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xhmrwhtv/3/ **NEW modified Working Fiddle**

```
function changeImage(imgName, obj)
{
     image = document.getElementById(obj.name);
     image.src = imgName;
     var name = obj.name;
     var selector = "input[checked][name='" + name +"']";
     currrentRadio = $(selector);
     currrentRadio.removeAttr("checked");

     $(obj).attr('checked', 'checked').prop("checked",true).trigger("click");
}
```

Comment: You code does not accomplish fully what he wants, need to modify so if I click lets say radio button 3 and then click the image it goes to image 1 and radio button 1, currently if I click the picture then click the first radio button then click the image again it goes to the 3rd image and radio button instead of the 2nd img and button.

Comment: Thank you a ton! The updated version seems like the best way to me since there is no javascript editing needed when new images are added in the future. Plus, I get the code and learned a lot. Again, thanks for the great help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tought about a simple JavaScript or jQuery script? This would not be hard to do, here is an example:

jQuery:

```
function slideSwitch() {
            var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

            if ($active.length == 0) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

            var $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next()
                : $('#slideshow IMG:first');

            $active.addClass('last-active');

            $next.css({ opacity: 0.0 })
                .addClass('active')
                .animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 1000, function () {
                    $active.removeClass('active last-active');
                });
        }

        $(function () {
            setInterval("slideSwitch()", 3000);
        });
```

html:

```
<div style="width: 100%; position: absolute; margin-top:5%;">
        <div id="slideshow" style="display: inline-block; position:relative;">
            <img src="pictures/coinWars/1.jpg" class="active" />
            <img src="pictures/coinWars/2.jpg"  />
            <img src="pictures/coinWars/3.jpg" />
            <img src="pictures/coinWars/4.jpg"  />
            <img src="pictures/coinWars/5.jpg"  />
            <img src="pictures/coinWars/6.jpg"  />
            <img src="pictures/coinWars/7.jpg"  />
            <img src="pictures/coinWars/8.jpg"  />
            <img src="pictures/coinWars/9.jpg"  />
            <img src="pictures/coinWars/10.jpg"  />
        </div>
```

That will make a simple slide show of pictures, you can change it to allow it to change on click, instead on on the interval.

This is my code, but feel free to use it and modify it as necessary.

Comment: Your code? you want to have a word with this guy for stealing it in 2008 [Jquery slides](http://jonraasch.com/blog/a-simple-jquery-slideshow)

Comment: excuse me, sorry that i use the same techniques. I wrote this a long time ago, if it happens to be like that, then my bad, but i believe i wrote all of that by hand.

Answer (score 0):

There are many javaScript sliders. You just need to search google to get your answer. However, following code may be helpful.

[Working Fiddle....](http://jsfiddle.net/khalid_iitdu/95bL55n9/5/)

```
<img id = "img" src = "http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-1.jpg" width = 200; onclick = "changeImage()">
<br>

    <input type="radio" name = "rdo" id = "radio1" onclick = "changeSlide(this)" checked />
    <input type="radio" name = "rdo" id = "radio2" onclick = "changeSlide(this)"/>
    <input type="radio" name = "rdo" id = "radio3" onclick = "changeSlide(this)"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
    function changeImage(){
    if(document.getElementById("img").src == "http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-1.jpg" ){
        document.getElementById("img").src = "http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-3.jpg";        
        document.getElementById("radio2").checked = true;
    }

    else if(document.getElementById("img").src == "http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-3.jpg"){
        document.getElementById("img").src ="http://www.userinterfaceicons.com/80x80/minimize.png";        
        document.getElementById("radio3").checked = true;
    }
    else if(document.getElementById("img").src == "http://www.userinterfaceicons.com/80x80/minimize.png"){
        document.getElementById("img").src = "http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-1.jpg";
        document.getElementById("radio1").checked = true;
    }
}

function changeSlide(id){
    if(document.getElementById("radio1")==id){           
        document.getElementById("img").src = "http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-1.jpg";
    }    
   else if(document.getElementById("radio2")==id){    
        document.getElementById("img").src = "http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-3.jpg";
    }    
    else if(document.getElementById("radio3")==id){        
        document.getElementById("img").src ="http://www.userinterfaceicons.com/80x80/minimize.png";
    }
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("radio2").checked = false;` is not necessary because if you do `document.getElementById("radio1").click();` it will take care of disabling the others since it is a radio button group.

Comment: @Simply Craig, [please have a look at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20983142/3186722). At least your concept will be clear....Thank you.

Comment: Right, except he did have them named the same, so you removed the name grouping to add more code?  Seems illogical. Add the name="image1" back and don't add so much useless code.

Answer (score 0):

First change you function to access the name not the object

```
function changeImage(imgName, name)
{
    image = document.getElementById(name);
    image.src = imgName;
}
```

Then then add to img onclick:

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" name="image1" id="image1" onclick="changeImageClick(1);"><br>
```

Then I added variables (just for the first set of changes:

```
var images1 = ["http://placehold.it/100x100","http://placehold.it/200x200","http://placehold.it/300x300"];
var images1num = 0;
```

images1num is for what current image src you are on.  Starting at 0 to 2.

Then you have to modify the radio buttons onclick to:

```
changeImage('http://placehold.it/200x200','image1'); images1num = 1;
```

Here is the function:

```
function changeImageClick(num)
{
    if(num == 1)
    {
        images1num = (images1num + 1) % images1.length;
        changeImage(images1[images1num],'image1');

        var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        var nextInput = false;   

        for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
        {
            if(input[i].checked == true && input[i].name == 'image1')
            {
                nextInput = true;

                 if(nextInput)
                {
                    input[(i+1)%images1.length].click();
                    nextInput = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Again this is only for your 100x100,200x200,300x300 but the concept works for all 3.

Here is JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v4phdL3p/44/

Replicating the other two sliders is a good learning experience.