# Why is my radio button list selecting more than one item in the list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two radio button lists that are allowing for more than one item on each list to be selected. These lists are being generated dynamically from an API data that is called using an AJAX call.

As you can see by the images below:

[image: List 01]
[image: List 02]

JavaScript and HTML code:

```js
 function listUnitOfMeasureSet_change() {
   if (listUnitOfMeasureSet.value.toString().toLowerCase() === "new") {
     $("#divNewTypeUnitContentHolder").html("");

     callService("GET", g_WebServiceUnitsOfMeasureTypeUnitsURL, null, "json", function(jsonResult) {
       if (jsonResult.Success) {
         for (i = 0; i < jsonResult.UnitOfMeasureTypeList.length; i++) {
           $("#divNewTypeUnitContentHolder").html($("#divNewTypeUnitContentHolder").html() + '<input type="radio" id="rblUnitOfMeasureType" value="' + jsonResult.UnitOfMeasureTypeList[i].ID + '" /> ' + jsonResult.UnitOfMeasureTypeList[i].Name + ' ' + jsonResult.UnitOfMeasureTypeList[i].Description + '<br />');
         }
       }
     });

     $("#divNewUnitOfMeasure").dialog("open");
   }
 }

 $("#divNewUnitOfMeasureBaseUnit").dialog({
   autoOpen: F,
   modal: T,
   title: "Unit Of Measure",
   width: 600,
   buttons: {
     Next: function() {
       $(this).dialog("close");
       $("#divNewUnitOfMeasureRelatedUnits").dialog("open");

       callService("GET", g_WebServiceUnitsOfMeasureRelatedUnitsGetAllByBaseUnitIDURL + '?BaseTypeID=' + $("input[type='radio'][id='rblUnitOfMeasureBaseUnit']:checked").val(), null, "json", function(jsonResult) {
         if (jsonResult.Success) {
           var data = {};

           for (var i = 0; i < jsonResult.UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitList.length; i++) {
             var row = {};
             row["UOMRelatedUnit_AddItem"] = F;
             row["UOMRelatedUnit_Abbreviation"] = jsonResult.UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitList[i].Abbreviation;
             row["UOMRelatedUnit_Active"] = jsonResult.UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitList[i].Active;
             row["UOMRelatedUnit_ConversionOfBaseUnits"] = jsonResult.UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitList[i].ConversionOfBaseUnits;
             row["UOMRelatedUnit_DisplayOrder"] = jsonResult.UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitList[i].DisplayOrder;
             row["UOMRelatedUnit_ID"] = jsonResult.UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitList[i].ID;
             row["UOMRelatedUnit_Name"] = jsonResult.UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitList[i].Name;
             row["UOMRelatedUnit_UnitOfMeasureBaseUnitID"] = jsonResult.UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitList[i].UnitOfMeasureBaseUnitID;
             data[i] = row;
           }
           var source = {
             localdata: data,
             datatype: "array",
             datafields: [{
               name: 'UOMRelatedUnit_ID',
               type: 'string'
             }, {
               name: 'UOMRelatedUnit_AddItem',
               type: 'bool'
             }, {
               name: 'UOMRelatedUnit_Name',
               type: 'string'
             }, {
               name: 'UOMRelatedUnit_Abbreviation',
               type: 'string'
             }, {
               name: 'UOMRelatedUnit_ConversionOfBaseUnits',
               type: 'number'
             }],
             addrow: function(rowid, rowdata, position, commit) {
               //Server Action
               commit(T);
             },
             updaterow: function(rowid, newdata, commit) {
               //Server Action
               commit(T);
             }
           };
           var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);

           $("#jqxUOMRelatedUnitsDropdownGrid").jqxGrid({
             width: 500,
             height: 200,
             source: dataAdapter,
             editable: T,
             selectionmode: 'singlecell',
             theme: 'energyblue',
             showtoolbar: T,
             rendertoolbar: function(toolbar) {
               var me = this;
               var container = $("<div style='margin: 5px;'></div>");
               toolbar.append(container);
               container.append('<input id="addUoMRelatedUnitsRowButton" type="button" value="Add New Row" />');
               container.append('<input style="margin-left: 5px;" id="addUoMRelatedUnitsMultipleRowsButton" type="button" value="Add Multiple New Rows" />');
               $("#addUoMRelatedUnitsRowButton").jqxButton();
               $("#addUoMRelatedUnitsMultipleRowsButton").jqxButton();

               // create new row.
               $("#addUoMRelatedUnitsRowButton").on('click', function() {
                 $("#jqxUOMRelatedUnitsDropdownGrid").jqxGrid('beginupdate');
                 var commit = $("#jqxUOMRelatedUnitsDropdownGrid").jqxGrid('addrow', null, ['']);
                 $("#jqxUOMRelatedUnitsDropdownGrid").jqxGrid('endupdate');
               });

               // create new rows.
               $("#addUoMRelatedUnitsMultipleRowsButton").on('click', function() {
                 $("#jqxUOMRelatedUnitsDropdownGrid").jqxGrid('beginupdate');
                 for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                   var commit = $("#jqxUOMRelatedUnitsDropdownGrid").jqxGrid('addrow', null, ['']);
                 }
                 $("#jqxUOMRelatedUnitsDropdownGrid").jqxGrid('endupdate');
               });
             },
             columns: [{
               text: '',
               editable: F,
               datafield: 'UOMRelatedUnit_ID',
               width: 0
             }, {
               text: 'Add',
               editable: T,
               datafield: 'UOMRelatedUnit_AddItem',
               columntype: 'checkbox',
               width: 40
             }, {
               text: 'Name',
               editable: T,
               datafield: 'UOMRelatedUnit_Name',
               columntype: 'textbox',
               width: 200
             }, {
               text: 'Abbreviation',
               editable: T,
               datafield: 'UOMRelatedUnit_Abbreviation',
               columntype: 'textbox',
               width: 100
             }, {
               text: '# of Base Unit',
               editable: T,
               datafield: 'UOMRelatedUnit_ConversionOfBaseUnits',
               columntype: 'textbox',
               width: 100
             }]
           });

           // select or unselect rows when the checkbox is checked or unchecked.
           $("#jqxUOMRelatedUnitsDropdownGrid").bind('cellendedit', function(event) {
             if (event.args.value) {
               $("#jqxUOMRelatedUnitsDropdownGrid").jqxGrid('selectrow', event.args.rowindex);
             } else {
               $("#jqxUOMRelatedUnitsDropdownGrid").jqxGrid('unselectrow', event.args.rowindex);
             }
           });
         }
       });
     },
     Back: function() {
       $(this).dialog("close");
       $("#divNewBaseUnitContentHolder").html('');
       $("#divNewUnitOfMeasure").dialog("open");
     },
     Cancel: function() {
       $(this).dialog("close");
     }
   }
 });
```

```html
<div id="divNewUnitOfMeasure">
  <strong>Select a Unit of Measure Type</strong>
  <br />If you don't see the Unit of Measure type you need, select Other to create a new one.
  <br />
  <div id="divNewTypeUnitContentHolder"></div>
</div>
<div id="divNewUnitOfMeasureBaseUnit">
  <strong>Select a Base Unit of Measure</strong>
  <br />
  <table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 100px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: top;">
        <div id="divNewBaseUnitContentHolder"></div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 200px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: top;">
        When you create inventory items, the base unit of measure should be the smallest increment used to track the item.
        <br />
        <br />For example, if you buy screws in bags of 100 but use one or two at a time, you should select a base unit of &quot;each&quot; instead of &quot;1 bag of 100.&quot;
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML radio buttons allowing multiple selections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982993/html-radio-buttons-allowing-multiple-selections)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All radio buttons that go together - that is, only one should be selectable - must have the same `name` attribute. Yours do not. Instead, you give them all the same `id` attribute, which results in invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of it, but you should add a name on the input radio.

On this line

```
$("#divNewTypeUnitContentHolder").html($("#divNewTypeUnitContentHolder").html() + '<input type="radio" id="rblUnitOfMeasureType" value="' + jsonResult.UnitOfMeasureTypeList[i].ID + '" /> ' + jsonResult.UnitOfMeasureTypeList[i].Name + ' ' + jsonResult.UnitOfMeasureTypeList[i].Description + '<br />');
```