# Multiples input type="radio" that can be selected and and deselected

Tags: html, forms, input, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I have the following code of inputs

```
<div id="especiality">
      <input type="radio" class="rad" name="Item1" value="Item1" />Publicidad
      <br />
      <input type="radio" class="rad" name="Item2" value="Item2" />Editorial
      <br />
      <input type="radio" class="rad" name="Item3" value="Item3" />Identidad Corporativa
      <br />
      <input type="radio" class="rad" name="Item4" value="Item4" />Web
      <br />
      <input type="radio" class="rad" name="Item5" value="Item5" />Empaques
      <br />
      <input type="radio" class="rad" name="Item6" value="Item6" />Tipografía
      <br />
      <input type="radio" class="rad" name="Item7" value="Item7" />Fotografía
      <br />
      <input type="radio" class="rad" name="Item8" value="Item8" />Señalética
      <br />
      <input type="radio" class="rad" name="Item9" value="Item9" />Animación
      <br />
      <input type="radio" class="rad" name="Item10" value="Item10" />Ilustración
      <br />
      </div>
```

That works with this script

```
<script>
          $(document).ready(function () {
              $("#button").click(function () {
                  // Radios
                  $(".rad:checked").each(function() {
                      console.log("Radio: " + $(this).val());
                  });
              });
          })
          </script>
```

It works for select multiples options and thats ok but it doesn't when it comes to deselect the option. Any solutions?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML radio buttons allowing multiple selections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982993/html-radio-buttons-allowing-multiple-selections)

Comment: Please try using google first. I typed your problem in and the first link I got was a very useful Stackoverflow post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982993/html-radio-buttons-allowing-multiple-selections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selector for unchecked items would be:
`$(".rad:not(:checked)").each(function() {`

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons are designed to let you select **exactly one** out of a group. You *can* start a group with zero selected (by omitting the checked attribute from all of them) but there isn't a clean way to go back to that state.

To group radio buttons, give them all the same name.

If you want to select zero or more from a group, you should be using checkboxes, not radio buttons.