# Make radio buttons single choice: Other way than taking the same name?

Tags: javascript, html

Radio buttons are the things to choose if you want to enable single choice. I know that this can be achieved when giving radio buttons the same name so this group  will then only accept a single button clicked and will disable another clicked radio button.

So my question is if there is another way to make radio buttons single-selectable without turning them into buttons that remove the "active"-class of other buttons when clicked (as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982993/html-radio-buttons-allowing-multiple-selections)).

I hope this isn't a duplicate question. Can you keep the appearance of a radio button which is important for me but make it single-selectable even if they have different names?

Edit:

I really want to stick with radio buttons because of the convention that they only provide single choice. Check boxes normally can be multi choice.
And I need to distinguish the elements by name and not by Id because of the code behind that already exists. I want to avoid refactoring this.

Comment: Why would you avoid giving them the same name?

Comment: Wouldn't checkboxes be more ideal for this sort of project?

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish? There is probably another way to accomplish it with leaving standard conventions in place.

Comment: "I want to avoid refactoring this." — Refactor it. It will be less pain than trying to hack something that isn't a radio group into acting like a radio group (and probably missing something and introducing an accessibility issue).

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are dealing with code that is not yours.

I advise you to refactor it and do it [the right way](http://www.punkchip.com/accessible-radiobuttons-checkboxes/).

`Radio input` have a purpose, not only on code but on accessibility. Also for `checkbox inputs`, so please respect that.

Trying to *reinvent the wheel* will bring you a lot of unnecessary problems.

Comment: Totally agree, great answer. Small note, it's _advise_ not _advice_ here.