# CSS Problems with radio checkboxes

Tags: css

i have a little problem with radio check boxes and havn't found any solution in this forum yet.

**It should only 1 radio checkbox be activated.**
If i click on the 2nd radio button, the first is still checked and when I check also the 3rd one, then all are checked and i'm not be able to uncheck one of them. I hope someone can help me.

```
    <input type="radio" checked class="frame_inner_1_open" id="frame_inner_1_open">
    <input type="radio" class="frame_inner_2_open" id="frame_inner_2_open">
    <input type="radio" class="frame_inner_3_open" id="frame_inner_3_open">

    <label for="frame_inner_1_open" id="frame_inner_1_icon_toggle">
      <div class="frame_inner_1_icon"></div>
    </label>


    <label for="frame_inner_2_open" id="frame_inner_2_icon_toggle">
      <div class="frame_inner_2_icon"></div>
    </label>


    <label for="frame_inner_3_open" id="frame_inner_3_icon_toggle">
      <div class="frame_inner_3_icon"></div>
    </label>
```

Comment: see mozilla for more of an explanation :- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

Comment: its name attribute problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML radio buttons allowing multiple selections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982993/html-radio-buttons-allowing-multiple-selections)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you expect your browser to understand that these radiobuttons belong to eachother? Just because they are next to one another clearly does not magically tell the browser that this is the case.

To accomplish this, you need to set the name attribute, and set it equally on all linked radiobuttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="foo" checked class="frame_inner_1_open" id="frame_inner_1_open">
<input type="radio" name="foo" class="frame_inner_2_open" id="frame_inner_2_open">
<input type="radio" name="foo" class="frame_inner_3_open" id="frame_inner_3_open">
```

Read documentation on how to use html controls.

Answer (score 2):

Set them the same `name` attribute

[Learn here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_radio_name.asp)

```html
    <input type="radio" name="rdb" checked class="frame_inner_1_open" id="frame_inner_1_open">
    <input type="radio" name="rdb" class="frame_inner_2_open" id="frame_inner_2_open">
    <input type="radio" name="rdb" class="frame_inner_3_open" id="frame_inner_3_open">

    <label for="frame_inner_1_open" id="frame_inner_1_icon_toggle">
      <div class="frame_inner_1_icon"></div>
    </label>


    <label for="frame_inner_2_open" id="frame_inner_2_icon_toggle">
      <div class="frame_inner_2_icon"></div>
    </label>


    <label for="frame_inner_3_open" id="frame_inner_3_icon_toggle">
      <div class="frame_inner_3_icon"></div>
    </label>
```