# How to mark checkbox checked in flask jinja if item exists in list?

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a list which has four values

```
list=['FE','FW','BE','BW']
```

and I have table in front end html, which has this four values has column with radio button. I am trying check the radio button corresponding to the item in list.
This is the code i am using :

```
<td><input type="radio"  id="FE" name="{{key}}"   Value="FE"  {% if 'FE' in list %}checked{% endif %}></td>
<td><input type="radio"  id="FW" name="{{key}}"   Value="FW"  {% if 'FW' in list %}checked{% endif %}></td>
<td><input type="radio"  id="BE" name="{{key}}"   Value="BE"  {% if 'BE' in list %}checked{% endif %}></td>
<td><input type="radio"  id="BW" name="{{key}}"   Value="BW"  {% if 'BW' in list %}checked{% endif %}></td>
```

The problem is the above is selecting only the last value, but when 'FE' is existing in the list its not selecting FE on the front end. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML radio buttons allowing multiple selections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982993/html-radio-buttons-allowing-multiple-selections)

Comment: try to inspect the code rendered in your browser, maybe not only "FE" is checked, inspect the code with Chrome is very simple: right click on the page --> inspect

Comment: Yes, Thanks.
i just looked and actually all values are getting checked, but when i have a " if 'FE' in list " statment, ist't it supposed to check only FE button? sorry i am new to this.