# how can I choose one option when I use foreach in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, drop-down-menu

[image]

**this is code in html :**

```
<div class="col-9">
    <form>
        <div class="multiselect">
            <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
                <select>
                    <option placeholder="www"></option>
                </select>
                <div class="overSelect"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="checkboxes">
                @foreach ($subjects as $subject)
                <label for="itemform">
                    <input type="radio" value="{{ $subject->id }}"/>{{ $subject->name }}
                </label>
                @endforeach
            </div>


            @error('subjects')
            <small class="form-text text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**and this is code in java script :**

```
<script>

    var expanded = false;

    function showCheckboxes() {
        var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
        if (!expanded) {
            checkboxes.style.display = "block";
            expanded = true;
        } else {
            checkboxes.style.display = "none";
            expanded = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

My question is how can I choose to select only one item from the list given that I used the type is radio

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio#defining_a_radio_group

Comment: `<label for="itemform">` - there is no element with the ID `itemform` in what you have shown, so what is this supposed to refer to? And even if there was, it would make no sense to have the labels of each individual radio button, all associated with _one_ single form element. You should leave out the `for` attribute completely here. (Since the input is wrapped _into_ the label, the label will automatically be associated with it.)

Comment: Radio buttons with the same `name` attribute always restrict you to only select one of the inputs. Just set a `name` attribute on the input, make sure it's unique for each row.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML radio buttons allowing multiple selections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982993/html-radio-buttons-allowing-multiple-selections)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this code,

```
<input type="radio" name="itmname" value="{{ $subject->id }}" />{{ $subject->name }}
```

use this script.

```
function showCheckboxes() {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("itmname");
    var checkboxesContainer = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
    var expanded = checkboxesContainer.style.display !== "block";

    checkboxesContainer.style.display = expanded ? "block" : "none";

    if (expanded) {
        for (var i = 1; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            checkboxes[i].checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```